# Prevent JQuery Datepicker's OnSelect function to Reset CSS

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I have a JQuery function inwhich I'm enabling only few dates using "**beforeShowDay**" function.
And I'm using onSelect function to get the selected date.
luckly both of'em are working fine.
However there is a problem here Once i select a date its background is changing only for small time again the highlighted background coming back  to current date.
If i remove onSelect function then its working fine.
please help here is my code:

```
var dates = [[2013, 2, 1],[2013, 2, 9],[2013, 2, 25],[2013,3,15]];

$(function(){
      $('[id="form1:kix_inline"]').datepicker(
      {
    beforeShowDay: function (date)
        {

          var x= dates.length;
      var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
      for (var i=0; i < x; i++)
      {
         if (year == dates[i][0] && month == dates[i][1] - 1 &&  day == dates[i][2])
         {
            return [true, 'ui-state-highlight ui-state-active'];
         }
       }
      return [false];
    },

    onSelect: function(value, date) {

         var frm = document.getElementById("sendDateForm");
         frm.submit();

    }
    });
});
```

**Problem:** 
 Initially the only few dates(mentioned in array above "dates") will be enabled. Once i click any  of those dates the "current date style" will only sit there for few seconds.,it bounces back to current date again.

Please Help [ I'm sorry i my explanation isn't clear]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're submitting a form in the onSelect function :

```
var frm = document.getElementById("sendDateForm");
    frm.submit();
```

The submit reloads the page, and that's why it only flashes the right color, and then reverts to the original date, the page has reloaded! If you need to send the form, and not reload the page, you'll have to use ajax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. but I don't know how to do that either. coz if its a normal jsp app then i can ajax submit to servlet, but now in JSF i have to submit the form to Managed bean. Please respond.